# Dbutils error: java.sql.SQLException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I'm implementing Dbutils using `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` driver in `jtds` package.

Problem is it gives me `java.sql.SQLException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` error even after including `jtds` jar in project. It works fine when i include this `jtds` jar file in lib folder of tomcat.

I checked build code, `jtds` jar file is present there.

```
java.sql.SQLException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:702)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:634)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:488)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
at com.cibil.crs.escalationmatrix.dbutil.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:46)
at com.cibil.crs.escalationmatrix.dbutil.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:17)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:237)
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1093)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:672)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:271)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Its not a `ClassNotFoundException`, but an `SQLException`. Please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace. Its not related to Classpath problem

Comment: added stacktrace. thanks

Comment: i think you r developing a web application in Eclipse, right? where you put the jtds.jar in your project?

Comment: It seems jtds jdbc driver is not in the classpath. Be sure jtds jdbc driver is in the runtime classpath. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Yes it is the `ClassNotFoundException`. Are you correctly adding the jar in the Project's build path ?

Comment: It's netbeans, when i create build 'jtds.jar' is present at Web-Inf/lib

Comment: This does not mean it will be in the classpath when you run your DbUtils as a standalone java application.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a connection pool and you are making use of the tomcat. See the link below, and notice the line that says "The fully qualified Java class name of the JDBC driver to be used. The driver has to be accessible from the same classloader as tomcat-jdbc.jar".

https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html